# Formatting TextboxFor content 

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyClass.MyValue, new { style = "width: 138px", id = "mTextBox", maxlength = 10 })
```

I'd like format the content. Where can I do this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Use

```
Html.TextBox("MyValue",String.Format('<your format>',Model.MyClass.MyValue))
```

for example "{0:d}" or "{0:c}"
or if you want to use only Html.TextBoxFor then u can format your content from model.

Comment: How to take culture into account?

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me..

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.INVOICE_DATE,"{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { maxlength = 10, style = "min-height:30px; min-height: 30px;  border-color: green; " })
```

Comment: To add value to this answer, please explain what was changed, and why it works.

Answer (score 3):

I've used EditorFor in a case such as this and decorated my property with DisplayFormat attribute

in my view:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)%>
```

and on my view model

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it, setting only the format string:
[TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fecha, "{0:G}", new { @class="vld-required" })
```

Answer (score 0):

for example to display the TimeStamp in ShortDate+ShortTime ("3/9/2010 4:15 PM")

```
Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyClass.TimeStamp, String.Format("{0:g}",Model.MyClass.TimeStamp))
```